# Dirichlet term in error estimations

Tags: finite-element, error-estimation, meshless-methods

I am working on a method based on moving least square approximation where shape functions  do not satisfy Kroneker Delta property. So Dirichlet boundary condition should be enforced.
I usually used penalty method for that. In the error estimation based on residual I used the following for Poisson equation:

\begin{align}
\eta^2=h_T^2\Vert  \Delta u+f \Vert^2+h_T^{-1} \Vert u-g_D\Vert^2_{\partial \Omega}.
\end{align} 
where
\begin{align}
-\Delta u=f, \quad u_{|\partial \Omega}=g_D.
\end{align}
Also, it should be noted that, because of the shape functions there is no jump between the internal elements.
The problem is that penalty parameter $\gamma$ should be bigger than $1e3$ to get good result. But for large $\gamma$ the effect of adaptive technique is not really good. All the time results by adaptive refinement is better than uniform. But when $\gamma$ is smaller for example $\gamma< 1e2$ the difference is remarkable. By these results I guess the term relates to Dirichlet boundary should be change by $\gamma$. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite well known in finite element research community that penalty methods easily lead to under/over refinement when used with adaptive methods, see for example the numerical examples in the end of [Juntunen, Stenberg: Nitsche's method for general boundary conditions](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-267/S0025-5718-08-02183-2/S0025-5718-08-02183-2.pdf) (page 1373). If you want to enforce the boundary conditions weakly, I would advise you to use Nitsche's method instead.